# When sending one email, the log shows the email twice? Though it's sending only once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

in my app, DJ fires off a an email but for some reason I see the email in the log file twice though it is sent only once? I confirmed in the logs that DJ runs only once and user_mailer runs only once. So why do I see the email twice in the log file? What is Rails doing?

```
Rendered user_mailer/room_notification.text.erb (0.9ms)

Sent mail to rachela.xxxxxxx@gmail.com (1097ms)
Date: Fri, 30 Sep 2011 13:34:56 -0700
From: "roomxcom" <no-reply@roomxcom>
To: rachela.xxxxxxx@gmail.com
Message-ID: <123@-MacBook-Pro.local.mail>
Subject: [Email Testing] Test 12
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

AAAAA Did something:

Test 12

http://localhost:3000/c19

Sent mail to rachela.xxxxxxx@gmail.com (3510ms)
Date: Fri, 30 Sep 2011 13:34:56 -0700
From: "roomxcom" <no-reply@roomxcom>
To: rachela.xxxxxxx@gmail.com
Message-ID: <123@-MacBook-Pro.local.mail>
Subject: [Email Testing] Test 12
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

AAAAA Did something:

Test 12

http://localhost:3000/c19
  SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  AREL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE "delayed_jobs"."id" = 25
  SQL (0.4ms)  COMMIT
```

**Delayed Job:**

```
UserMailer.delay.room_notification(room, record.user, room_member.user, record.item)
```

**User Mailer:**

```
def room_notification(room, user_creator, user_recipient, item)
  ...
mail( :from => "XXXX <no-reply@XXXXXXXXXX.com>",
      :to => user_recipient.email,
      :subject => "[#{@room.title}] #{@item.title}"
    ).deliver
```

Any idea what' going on and why rails is showing the email in the log twice? Thanks

Comment: May be because for the first time ur delayed job failed and then queued again and then in second attempt job was successful. Paste the output of rake jobs:work.

Comment: Mohit, that's not it. DJ is empty instantly after this run.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

edit: Here's a clearer explanation now that it's daytime and I've had some coffee...

This line is adding the message to the queue:

```
UserMailer.delay.room_notification(room, record.user, room_member.user, record.item)
```

So Delayed_job then calls the `room_notification` method in `UserMailer` to send the mail:

```
def room_notification(room, user_creator, user_recipient, item)
  # ...
  mail(:from => "XXXX <no-reply@XXXXXXXXXX.com>",
       :to => user_recipient.email,
       :subject => "[#{@room.title}] #{@item.title}"
  ).deliver
end
```

This would be enough in itself to send the mail but you also have a redundant `.deliver` on the end of the `mail` method so it's sending it twice.

TL;DR Remove `.deliver` from `mail(...)` in the `room_notification` method and everything should be fine.

Comment: I uses delay to send to DJ. Then DJ delivers. Isn't that the way it's done?

Comment: `UserMailer.delay.room_notification(room, record.user, room_member.user, record.item)` will add it to the DJ queue but you're also sending it immediately with `mail(...).deliver`.

Comment: Simon. The user mailer isn't called until delayed job? So I'm not following?

Comment: I've edited my answer so hopefully it should make more sense now :)